# Following the official Django tutorial and after making templates, I am having an issue with an int conversion

Tags: python, django

I am at the Django tutorial right here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render and I am stuck.

Currently, when I try to go to 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/{ any arbitrary number }/, Django throws a ValueError because it cannot convert '{ num }/'.

This is the exact error:

```
ValueError at /polls/1/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/'
```

This is the detail.html file:

```
{[ question }}
```

And this is the detail function polls/views.py:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist.")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
def results(request, question_id):
    response = HttpResponse("You are looking at the results of question %s.")
```

and this is the polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        # ex: /polls/
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        # ex: /polls/5/
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)', views.detail, name='detail'),
        # ex: /polls/5/results/
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
        # ex: /polls/5/vote/
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
          ]
```

Why is Django trying to cast '1/' to an int? This is the whole project if there are more files you need to look at: https://github.com/wOstensen/my-new-blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Your slash is *inside* the regex capture group.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I still haven't got a good grip on regex. :p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your url regex:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)
```

It should be:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', ...)
```